# GLSL can't compile a shader without interpolation (flat)

Tags: c++, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm drawing a complete object with mutiple meshes from a  single vertex/index buffer, and they have different textures.  Thus, I thought of passing ID of texture along with the vertices from vertex shader to fragments in the fragment shader. The problem is disabling the interpolation. I'm using `GLSL ver 3.3` with SDL2 and glew on MingW.

I've tried `flat out uint frag_MeshID;` instead of `out uint frag_MeshID;` in the vertex shader, but still I get this error while compiling the fragment shader:

`'frag_MeshID' : int/uint varying in is not flat interpolated`

This is my corresponding fragment shader snippet: `in uint frag_MeshID;`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this appears to be a wrong assumption I made. The fragment shader also needs the flat keyword. (I thought the vertex shader flat attribute will make the uint flat for next level)

So, this as fragment shader works: `flat in uint frag_MeshID;`
(with vertex shader: `flat out uint frag_MeshID;`)